# Проблема с перехватом трафика

Tags: android, сервер, безопасность, auth

Делаю систему аунтефикации и вроде как учтёл все моменты, но один момент мне не даёт покоя - перехват трафика.

Пишу приложение под Android которое связывается с сервером. Также присуствует система входа в аккаунт. На сервере используется HTTPS и сертификат SSL. В таблице SQL лежат пароли пользователя которые хешированны с помощью md5 чтобы при краже БД пароли пользователей не раскрылись.

Когда в приложении пользователь вводит пароль и он отправляется на проверку к серверу то при успешном сравнении паролей сервер выдаёт специальный ключ для пользователя который сохраняется в `SharedPreferences`. Когда пользователь хочет получить/изменить какую-то информацию то каждый раз высылается его ключ который сервер уже расшифровывает и сравнивает с паролем пользователя и если они совпадают то разрешить изменения этой информации.

Более наглядно как происходит выдача этого ключа. Есть пароль который лежит захешированный в БД. При выдаче ключа доступа для пользователя этот захешированный пароль ещё раз шифруется только с помощью самого сервера чтобы потом он его мог расшифровать. Тоесть пользователю выдался зашифрованный пароль который только сервер может расшифровать.

Вроде как всё безопасно, но есть проблема против которой я незнаю как бороться это перехват трафика. По сути если злоумышленник перехватит трафик то он получит тот самый ключ пользователя а тоесть он потом вручную сможет отправить этот запрос на сервер и получить нужную о пользователе информацию. Возникает вопрос как быть?

Comment: Для перехвата трафика злоумышленнику понадобиться осуществить mitm атаку на https. Это возможно только в случае если в приложении выключена проверка сертификата на https. Или если злоумышленник получит рут доступ к устройству и добавит собственные корневые сертификаты в систему. Но имея такой доступ к устройству он и так сможет сделать что угодно и перехват ключа ему будет ни к чему

Comment: Но вообще не стоит в ключ включать пароль. Включайте в ключ например id сессии, id пользователя и еще какие нибудь полезные данные. После чего все это шифруйте и/или подписывайте каким нибудь хешем (md5 тот же, хотя он уже признан не безопасным, лучше в сторону sha посмотреть). Тогда в случае компрометации ключа или в каких либо других случаях вы его просто отзываете (помечаете где то в БД у себя что эта сессия не валидна или удаляете сессию из БД) и все, перехваченный ключ не работает, при том что пароль менять не потребовалось

Comment: Спасибо за ответ забыл упомянуть что в приложение важно чтобы пользователь один раз вошёл в аккаунт и больше не требовалось в таком случаи как генерировать новый id сессии зная что это делает владелец аккаунта?

Comment: Кроме этого могут использоваться ключи с коротким сроком действия и автоматический обмен ключа на более свежий по предъявлению второго ключа. Так собственно многие системы сейчас работают, например авторизация в гугле, эппле, социальных сетях, основанная на JWT

Comment: Ну вот, как раз об этом и речь, что делают два ключа, один более секретный, который по сети гораздо реже ходит (например раз в час) и он позволяет получить сессионный ключ

Comment: Спасибо теперь я знаю в какую сторону мне двигаться. Раньше незнал о JWT

Comment: Про certificate pinning почитайте еще.